# How to run a karate script using power-shell command prompt

Tags: karate

In power-shell window command prompt how to run a karate script. can you briefly explain the process on this.

Comment: Hey, did you have a look at the documentation https://github.com/intuit/karate and maybe some demos or examples. Looking at the readme in the official repo they have a https://github.com/intuit/karate#command-line section. Maybe this will help.

Answer (score 2):

Download the standalone JAR file: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#standalone-jar

Assuming you have the JAR and feature file in the same directory, you can trigger the script from the command prompt using the following command:

```
> karate.jar testscript.feature
```

Comment: there's also a ZIP-release that is available: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/ZIP-Release

Comment: Actually in normal command prompt it's working fine. but in power-shell command prompt if we give like the same the target folder is not creating. So i want the steps how to run in Powers-hell command window.

Comment: Try: .\karate.jar testscript.feature

Comment: I tried with this,but the Target folder is not creating in the directory.

Comment: Try this: java -jar "%~dp0\karate.jar" testscript.feature